# Django filebased cacheing per site

Tags: django, caching

I am trying to add a cache to my site so it loads quicker, so I was just going to keep it simple and use the per-site option, with a file based system, but for some reason I must be missing something because it's not working.

edit:
I also have these:

```
'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
```

end edit.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/www/site.com/cache',
    }
}

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'sitealias'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 180
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = ''
```

From what I understand this should save any requests to the file backend at /var/www/site.com/cache for 180 seconds. What else do I need to do to make it work?

EDIT:
I think it may be to do with the google cookies, which I am now looking in to a work around.

ANOTHER EDIT:
It's not google that's the problem. Removed it and the issue remained.

Comment: did you make that directory writeable by the server?

Comment: Yeah I just made sure it is writeable by apache (as www-data). Restarted the server and refreshed, but nothing appears in the cache

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser www-data 4096 Apr  5 04:17 cache

Comment: That means it's not writable by www-data, the user apache runs as. Just make it 777 and test again.

Comment: Would 775 be ok? That way world doesn't get to have any access?

Comment: I tried both with no differing result! 
drwxrwxrwx 2 name www-data 4096 Apr  5 04:17 cache

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the cache middleware is enabled: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-per-site-cache

Also, mind you, if you're logged in the admin, you won't get cached pages.

Comment: I have made sure I am logged out, but I have the middle ware in the settings.py. I have edited my post to reflect this :D They are in the order shown.

Answer (score 0):

[Django's sessions, caching, and google analytics don't play well together](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/The-state-of-per-site-per-view-middleware-caching-in-Django-td486447.html).

Sounds like this isn't your problem, but I'll post this here as it may help others who find this.